# Encoding error with TwitterSearch in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I want to use TwitterSearch to import tweets into a csv. However, the script doesn't catch special caracters (for example accents in French). I've tried several things, like adding .encode('utf-8'), without any success.

If I try to write :

```
tweet_text = tweet['text'].strip().encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Then I get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/usr/Documents/Python/twitter_search2.py", line 56, in <module> get_tweets(query, max_tweets) File "/Users/usr/Documents/Python/twitter_search2.py", line 44, in get_tweets print('@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text)) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Does anybody have an idea?

I'm on Python 2.7. The code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from TwitterSearch import *
import csv


def get_tweets(query, max = 10):

    i = 0
    search = query

    with open(search+'.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        writer = csv.writer(outf)
        writer.writerow(['user','time','tweet','latitude','longitude'])
        try:
            tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
            tso.set_keywords([search])
            tso.set_include_entities(True)

           # tso.set_language('fr')

            ts = TwitterSearch(
                consumer_key = 'YOUR CONSUMER KEY',
                consumer_secret = 'YOUR CONSUMER SECRET',
                access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN',
                access_token_secret = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET'
            )

            for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
                lat = None
                long = None
                time = tweet['created_at']
                user = tweet['user']['screen_name']
                tweet_text = tweet['text'].strip().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                tweet_text = ''.join(tweet_text.splitlines())
                print i,time,
                if tweet['geo'] != None and tweet['geo']['coordinates'][0] != 0.0: # avoiding bad values
                    lat = tweet['geo']['coordinates'][0]
                    long = tweet['geo']['coordinates'][1]
                    print('@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text)), lat, long
                else:
                    print('@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text))

                writer.writerow([user, time, tweet_text, lat, long])
                i += 1
                if i > max:
                    return()

        except TwitterSearchException as e:
            print(e)


query = raw_input ("Recherche : ")
max_tweets = 10
get_tweets(query, max_tweets)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So *what error* do you get? Please include the full traceback.

Comment: With this code, the script is working, but special caracters are ignored and don't appeared in the sentence. I'm trying to find a way to include them.

Comment: Yes, because you encode the text to ASCII and ignore everything that doesn't fit. That's a lot of things to not fit.

Comment: I'm confused :/ If I try to write :

                    tweet_text = tweet['text'].strip().encode('utf-8', 'ignore')

Then I get 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/Documents/Python/twitter_search2.py", line 56, in <module>
    get_tweets(query, max_tweets)
  File "/Users/usr/Documents/Python/twitter_search2.py", line 44, in get_tweets
    print('@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Looks like *some* of your tweets are not Unicode but byte strings. Then you get an implicit *decoding* first before you can *encode*. Can you include that in your question?

Comment: Or, rather, it could be TwitterSearch returns byte strings *always*; you have encoded data already and don't need to encode *agin*. What does `type(tweet['text'])` say you have? What does `print repr(tweet['text'])` say is in the value?

Comment: @Martjin Oh maybe we have something! With print repr(tweet['text']), special caracters are displayed as \xab \xbb \xe9 etc.

Comment: Sure, but does it start with `u'` or just `'`?

Comment: Then you still have Unicode objects and `.encode('utf8') ` should just work. Can you use a `try:...except UnicodeDecodeError:` to catch *just* the objects that throw the exception and look at those? And please [edit] your question to add that kind of information.

Comment: Ah, wait. Your traceback shows you are **printing**. It is the printing that fails here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interpolating the encoded tweet together with the *username*:

```
print('@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text))
```

If the `user` object is a Unicode string this'll fail:

```
>>> user = u'Héllo'
>>> tweet_text = u'Héllo'.encode('utf8')
>>> '@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

because you are mixing types. Python tries to *decode* the `tweet_text` value to make it a `unicode` object again.

Stick to *one type*; either encode everything, or leave everything Unicode, and encode at the last instance.

You'll have to encode your `user` value for the CSV file anyway, leave encoding of the tweet until then:

```
tweet_text = tweet['text'].strip()
tweet_text = u''.join(tweet_text.splitlines())
print i, time,
if tweet['geo'] and tweet['geo']['coordinates'][0]: 
    lat, long = tweet['geo']['coordinates'][:2]
    print u'@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text), lat, long
else:
    print u'@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text)

writer.writerow([user.encode('utf8'), time.encode('utf8'), 
                 tweet_text.encode('utf8'), lat, long])
```

Comment: Waow! It works perfectly, and I understand the logic behind it. Thank you so much.

I'll send the comment to the writer of the library too, if it can help someone else.

Thank you.